# Two variable power series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I was reading P.L. Duren's Univalent Functions and got stuck in trying to figure out how he had expanded the following expression in page 119:
$$\frac{\zeta g'(\zeta)}{g(\zeta)-g(z)}-\frac{\zeta}{\zeta-z}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\beta_{nk}z^{-k}\zeta^{-n},\tag{1}$$ with |z|>1 and $|\zeta|>1$. We are given the following information $g(z)=z+b_0+b_1z^{-1}+....$ and can be expanded as $$\frac{\zeta g'(\zeta)}{g(\zeta)-g(z)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n(w)\zeta^{-n}\tag{2}$$ with $F_n(w)=w^n+\sum_{n=1}^{n}a_{nk}w^{n-k}$.

I tried to rewrite the first term of the left hand side of (1) using (2) and expand the second term using a geometric expansion but I end up with coefficients $\beta_{nk}$ depending on z and $\zeta$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1 above is just the general Laurent series for an analytic function of two variables $|z|, |\zeta| >1$ which is zero at infinity separately in each variable  (hence all strictly negative powers and no separate terms like $z^{-k}$ or $\zeta^{-k}$ ) so the only thing to prove is that indeed LHS of 1 is analytic at $z=\zeta$ and is zero at infinity in $\zeta$ (for fixed $z$) as the rest is obvious from univalence of $g$; second follows from the fact that $g$ is univalent so $g'(\zeta) \ne 0$, while first from basic Taylor estimates once you bring all to common denominator

Comment: Thanks for the help!